# Last file in loop not written during interpreter session

Tags: python

I am trying to write the lists into a file. My code writes all the list except last list. I don't know why. Can someone please take a look at my code and let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
complete_test=[['apple','ball'],['test','test1'],['apple','testing']]
counter = 1
for i in complete_test:
    r=open("testing"+str(counter)+".txt",'w')
    for j in i:
        r.write(j+'\n')
    counter=counter +1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Call `r.close()` after your loop.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Why does it write in 2 files but not the last?

Comment: What Python are you using?  This works fine for me, producing all 3 files.

Comment: Also, Python closes files on block exit.

Comment: @Prune: it has to do with file flushing. It's not necessarily a python-specific issue - it could even come from the OS

Comment: @Prune I am using python 2.7. Solution Arya provided worked. I just want to know why did my code not write the last list.

Comment: @OzgurVatansever I am using 2.7

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I saw your answer and it works. I just want to know why it writes 2 list but not the last list. Thank you :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `r.close()`.

---

This doesn't happen if you run your code as a Python file, but it's reproducible in the interpreter, and it happens for this reason:

All of the changes to a file are buffered, rather than executed immediately. CPython will close files when there are no longer any valid references to them, such as when the only variable referencing them is overwritten on each iteration of your loop. (And when they are closed, all of the buffered changes are flushed—written out.) On the final iteration, you never close the file because the variable `r` sticks around. You can verify this because calling `exit()` in the interpreter closes the file and causes the changes to be written.

---

This is a motivating example for context managers and `with` statements, as in inspectorG4dget's answer. They handle the opening and closing of the files for you. Use that code, rather than *actually* calling `r.close()`, and understand that this is what's going when you do it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  This explains a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a much cleaner way of doing the same thing:

```
complete_test=[['apple','ball'],['test','test1'],['apple','testing']]

for i,sub in enumerate(complete_list, 1):  # `enumerate` gives the index of each element in the list as well
    with open("testing{}".format(i), 'w') as outfile:  # no need to worry about opening and closing, if you use `with`
        outfile.write('\n'.join(sub))  # no need to write in a loop
        outfile.write('\n')
```